# Making a UIButton with an imageView look disabled without setting isEnabled to false

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have some UIButtons that I disable by setting button.isEnabled = false.  I found that I need to still be able to access the buttons presses when they are disabled. So, I need to leave the buttons enabled but make them look disabled.  This should be possible by changing the color of the image/text of the button.  The buttons have a imageView that changes color for isEnabled and isHighlighted. If I stop setting isEnabled the imageView no longer changes.  As an experiment I added text to the button.titleLabel and I can see both the imageView and the titleLabel on the button.  I can set button.titleLabel.isEnabled = false and see the titleLabel go to grey but the imageView stays lit.  I haven't found an equivalent to isEnabled for the imageView. I have tried may things to change the imageView color but UIButton seems determined that only it should change the image color and only when the button.isEnabled is set.  Is there a way to make the image color change programmatically?

I've checked all the suggested questions but they are all setting isEnabled.

Comment: You can change alpha value of button to look like disabled

Comment: The current usage, where I use isEnabled, just greys the image in the button.  I would like to duplicate this functionality.  I tried changing the imageView.alpha but has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Seems the problem was that in my xcassetts I had the "Render As" set to default for the images.  If I forced it to use "Original Image" I had the same issue I am having now.  Why setting button.isEnabled = false worked is unknown, except it was probably Apple being too clever by half.  If I set it to "Template Image" I could then effect the button.imageView.tintColor. Which I knew from loading images programmatically.

So, the steps are:

1. make sure the image is set to template in the xCassetts.
2. Set the initial tintColor in IB or programmatically as:

   `button?.imageView?.tintColor = UIColor.white`
3. Then in the code to change the color based upon a boolean *value* is:

   `button?.imageView?.tintColor = value ? UIColor.white : UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)`

I also found that I could use the tintAdjustmentMode using the code:

```
`button?.imageView?.tintAdjustmentMode  = value ? .normal : .dimmed`
```

and it would dim the image, probably as much as the button.isEnabled = false did.  I found I liked the alpha at 0.5 better because it was more pronounced.

Answer (score 1):

set the button's titleColor and titleImage for the normal state to make the button look disabled but not be disabled...

there is no convenience method for 'fakeIsEnabled' so you gotta do it manually

Comment: Daij-Djan, thanks for you input.  You mean setTitleColor(UIColor,for:.normal) and image(UIImage:for:.normal) but this would require me creating separate images in my xcassetts. But, your comment and acknowledgement that is was possible made me give it another look this morning and I found the problem. So it was helpful.